# How to use Stage Video (Flash Player 10.2)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, stage

How can I use Stage Video in my project in Flash Professional CS5?

Do I need Flex Hero for it? Are there any good examples of using Stage Video?
I've tried to create something but Flash Pro gave me an error - he doesn't know what StageVideoAvailabilityEvent means.

Comment: I like that you attribute a pronoun to Flash, the Old Man.

Comment: StageVideo is not specific to the Flex framework so you can most certainly use it in Flash Professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being new, there aren't too many tutorials out there for StageVideo - but [here is one that should prove enlightening](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/How-to-use-Stage-video-new-to-flash-player-10.2/66096).

If you are getting reference errors, it simply means you either aren't importing the class properly, or that you aren't using the latest flex sdk. I believe you need 4.5, which can be downloaded for free from [Adobe](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK).

Answer (score 1):

here is a better learning resource for StageVideo by Thibault Imbert at Adobe:  [Getting started with stage video](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html)

have a read of the documentation ([flash.media.StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html)) first to familiarize yourself with the API.